# Is the expression, "...it extended miles and miles around..." correct?

Tags: expressions, sentence

Example:

> The forest extended miles and miles around the house.

Is that expression grammatically correct? Does it make sense?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This sort of doubling is an informal way to emphasise number or extent.

Taken literally it means "it extends for miles, and then it extends for more miles beyond that," which is perfectly reasonable.

It may seem redundant, but it is adding emphasis beyond mere "miles" without having to be more precise than that

It's also a well-known idiom that helps comprehension, though could perhaps be best not overly used, if only because all emphasis becomes weakened if you overuse it.